# why when i use animation the position of the item change?

Tags: html, css

I want to make like this design: [image: design]
When the animation work, the position of the two circles (pseudo-elements) change, so it spoils the shape.

**My Questions:**

*-Why the position of the two pseudo elements change when the animation is working?
-How can I rotate the two pseudo-elements without spoil the shape?*

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 0px solid;
  border-color: #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264 transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264 transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #2196f3 transparent #2196f3 #2196f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Elzero</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you can try removing the css top, left and transform properties on ::before and ::after. For example:

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
  div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 0px solid;
    border-color: #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264 transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;

    }
  div::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264 transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: #2196f3 transparent #2196f3 #2196f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Elzero</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: when I remove top and left, the two circles are not around the main circle before the animation run.

Comment: @fadisafou Updated answer, you need to also remove transform property on ::before and ::after